# Is there an easy way to determine which parts of a vb.net project is still used?

Tags: vb.net, usage-statistics

I maintain an old vb.net project that I didn't make and I was wondering if there's an easy way to determine which parts of the software is still used today by the staff where I work.

I would like to log all function calls without having to edit each one of them if possible.

The project has 27 forms and 6 modules.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: 27 forms, 6 modules and no (non-form) classes? I highly recommend just throwing the whole project away and starting from scratch. This is guaranteed to be a steaming pile of unmaintainable crap, sorry. (Your question is still interesting though.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to 100% determine everything that is used by the system.  Vb.Net supports dynamic invocation of methods / properties.  Hence you can't even do tricks like delete some code and see if it recompiles.  Even if it compiles it could be invoked dynamically.

One way to get a sense of what code is used is to profile the application.  Start up the profiler, run the app and go through all of the ways in which the app is used.  The resulting profile should give you a good sense of what parts are used.  It's very possible though this approach will miss code though

Comment: I was thinking of a logging approach since I have no idea which of the software's features the staff are using.

Comment: @brunoqc in that situation logging is probably better because it would be hard to setup the profiler for all of the staff.  I think you'll end up doing more work introducing a logging infrastructure than you would save by deleting code though :(